# Can we translate 3d data into faked 2d data? It seems possible to fake 3d by using 2d images.changing size and shape

Tags: 3d-view, units, 2d, 3d-manipulator

There is a some excitement about using an animation platform for web sites.  People say it is powerful and fast.  So, for employment purposes since I am a software engineer, I have taken the task of learning it.  The first thing I looked into is if it can do 3D.  It doesn't really, but it fakes it a number of ways by changing scale.

But then I found a youtube instruction of someone who found how to fake it by animation shape and scale of rectangles to simulate looking at a laptop cover opening and closing in a convincing way.

At this point, I should say that I are just starting out learning Blender.  I wonder if blender offers some way of translating 3d mesh representations into a 2d platform.  If you think of it, all 3d is converted in some way into 2d.  And, in reality, 3d is faked in a way in order for us to view it on a computer monitor.

UPDATE:

So that you can understand what I mean, here is the video I am talking about thst is showing the web designer fake a 3d object by using 2d objects: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Tl81lwianI&t=721s

And I found this as well showing a 3d cube made by software. If you look at this carefully, you can see what I mean when I say that it is really just a manipulaiton nof 2d polygons -- in this case, quadralaterials (if you remember high school geometry): https://youtu.be/qZypA-syPco

Comment: Currently it's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish and what you mean by "fake" 2D/3D. Perhaps you can elaborate and show example images?

Comment: If I understand your question, this is exactly what most 3D software do, when every object is represented as a sum of little triangular planar faces (when rendering a 3D space into a 2D representation), which are scaled and moved according to the desired shape; even quads and Ngons get triangulated at the rendering stage, so that 3 vertices define a plane, with its own normal direction. Your simplification example can work for planar objects (like a laptop cover), but will fail for more complex objects. So, maybe, you are looking for a very simple and "light computing" render engine.

Comment: So that you can understand what I mean, here is the video I am talking about thst is showing the web designer fake a 3d object by using 2d objects: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Tl81lwianI&t=721s

And I found this as well showing a 3d cube made by software. If you look at this carefully, you can see what I mean when I say that it is really just a manipulaiton nof 2d polygons -- in this case, quadralaterials (if you remember high school geometry): https://youtu.be/qZypA-syPco